# Checking for derived class type

Tags: c++, derived-class

This is an example of a problem I have while designing an interface.

I have a class Animal and I have derived Cat, Dog and Lion from it. Now I have a function 'feedFood' which takes in the base class Animal as parameter. Based on the type of animal I should feed different food to the Animal.

So how do I check the type of the animal in the 'feedFood' function.

There are 3 methods I could think of

- Adding a 'AnimalType' enum in the base class which is set to the right type in the derived class.
- Add a virtual function in base class to return a string with animal type. In derived class return the proper string for the animal name.
- Use typeid or dynamic_cast to check the type of the derived class in the 'feedFood' function.

Which is the best method or is there any other better approach for this?

Comment: Scott Meyers once said "Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form "if the object is of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do something else," slap yourself". On a more serious note, can't you just make `feedFood` virtual?

Comment: Or, if `feedFood` can't be virtual, maybe `FoodType hisFavoriteFood()` can be virtual, and non-virtual `feedFood()` could invoke it.

Comment: Shouldn't one of you write an answer I could upvote?  This is precisely what virtual functions were designed to do.

Comment: You may need *double dispatch" if each `Animal` requires different food.  Although in that case, each animal should have a separate feeding method because it has different food requirements.

Answer (score 7):

You are currently saying this:

```
void feedFood(Animal &);

Cat myCat;
Dog myDog;

feedFood(myCat);
feedFood(myDog);

// Problem: How does feedFood() know what's going on?
```

To use polymorphism, make the feeding function a virtual member of `Animal`:

```
struct Animal
{
  virtual void feedFood() = 0; // pure virtual or default behaviour, up to you
  virtual ~Animal() { }        // always provide virtual destructor!
  /* ... */
};

struct Cat : public Animal
{
  void feedFood() { /* Cat implementation */ }
  /* ... */
};

// Usage:

// via reference
void feed(Animal & a) { a.feedFood(); }

// via pointer
Animal * b = new Bat;
b->feedFood();
```

Comment: In my example `feedFood` is not part of Animal class and the implementation is not known to Animal class.

Comment: Can you change the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Animal{};
class Dog: public Animal{};
class Cat: public Animal{};
class Lion: public Animal{};

void FeedFood(Dog& d)
{
    cout << "Feeding the dog.\n";
    return;
}

void FeedFood(Cat& c)
{
    cout << "Feeding the cat.\n";
    return;
}

void FeedFood(Lion& l)
{
    cout << "Feeding the lion.\n";
}

void FeedFood(Animal& a)
{
    cout << "Feeding an unknown animal.\n";
    return;
}
```

With the above functions, the compiler will take care of feeding animals.

Sometimes, functionality may be better placed outside the class.

Comment: No, that only works with static types.  Given an `Animal *`, and a desire to feed different animals separately, you do need virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, somewhat complicated, but resolves at compile time:

```
template <class _Derived>
class Animal
{};

class Dog: public Animal<Dog>
{
public:
    void Feed()
    {
        cout<<"Feeding Dog...";         
    }
};

class Cat: public Animal<Cat>
{
public:
    void Feed() { /* Feed Cat*/ }  
};
```

And implement ONE template function:

```
template<class _AnimalType>
void FeedAnimal(_AnimalType& animal)
{
    animal.Feed();
}
```

Create instance of any class, and call **FeedAnimal**:

```
Dog dog;
Cat cat;
FeedAnimal(dog);
FeedAnimal(cat);
```

If Feed is not implemented by **derived-class**, you may not get error, until you call Feed template function. Therefore, if Lion is implemented like:

```
class Lion : public Animal<Lion>
{};
```

You won't get any error that Feed is missing from class. As soon as you make call to FeedAnimal with Lion, you would get error that Lion is missing Feed method.

This is one of the hack to ensure that derived class implements Feed:

```
template <class _Derived>
class Animal
{
    void (_Derived::*pDummy)();
public:
    Animal()
    {
        pDummy = &_Derived::Feed;       
    }
};
```

Dirty, but works!

Comment: For reference, the techniques used in this post are "Compile Time Polymorphism" and "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern".

Answer (score 0):

Not the animal gets food feeded, but it ates it. So add a virtual 'eat' method together with some FoodProvider on which the Animal can eat on.

**Update**:

So instead of an

```
void feed (const Food & food);
```

use

```
virtual void eatFrom (FoodProvider * provider);
```

That way you can also implement different food resources in your provider.

Comment: What relevance does this have?

Comment: He can add two polymorphisms:
- the behavior of an animal eating (what it wants to eat) by overwriting the eatFrom method
- overloading the behavior to react on the animals food constraints by subclassing FoodProvider (e.g. counting the mouses to give out to a cat).
Of course it has to be named "eatFrom" not "ateFrom", my fault.